# What is the difference between side effect and referential transparency?

Tags: functional-programming

What is the difference between these terms?

- a function has no side effect
- a function is referential transparent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A function that is referentially transparent definitely has no side effects. However, a function that has no side effects is not always referentially transparent.

Examples:

```
int x = 0;

int referentiallyTransparent(int y)
{
    return y + 1;
}

int hasNoSideEffects(int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

The function `hasNoSideEffects` has no side effects. Which means that calling `hasNoSideEffects(y)` does not affect the state of the program. However, the value it returns is affected by the state of the program and does not solely depend on the input variable `y` and thus a call `hasNoSideEffects(y)` cannot always be replaced by the value it reduces to.

Comment: So, a side effect free function does not change shared state, and in addition of that a ref transparent function does not read shared state.

Comment: Not only does not read shared state - it must be deterministic (a random function would not read shared state nor change it, and, yet, not be referentially transparent).

Comment: Suggested reading: [Nondeterminism with Referential Transparency in Functional Programming Languages](https://academic.oup.com/comjnl/article-pdf/31/3/243/1157325/310243.pdf) by F. Warren Burton.